# Creating TIN using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, tin

I am attempting to creating a TIN using arcPy. When I try, I receive an error saying "The value is not a member of . Failed to execute (CreateTin)." Is there any solution to fix this? I am including some of the lines above this step to ensure they are not causing the issue.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = Output_Folder
elev_points = "point"
elev_points_shp= "point.shp"
TIN = "TIN"
arcpy.env.workspace = GDB_Name
DTM = "DTM"
name = "FILE"
LRM = "LRM"
TERRAIN= "TERRAIN"

# Process: Focal Statistics
SmoothDEM2 = FocalStatistics(SmoothDEM, neighborhood2, "MEAN")

# Process: Minus
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
outMinus = arcpy.sa.Minus(SmoothDEM, SmoothDEM2)
outMinus.save(r"outaMinus")

# Process: Contour
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.sa.Contour(outMinus, break_lines, "10000", "0")

# Process: Extract by Mask
extract_elev = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(SmoothDEM, break_lines)

# Process: Raster to Point
arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(extract_elev, elev_points, "Value")
print ("raster to point done")

# Process: Create TIN
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3d")
arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(elev_points, Output_Folder, elev_points_shp)
arcpy.ddd.CreateTin(TIN, "", "elev_points_shp grid_code Mass_Points <None>", "DELAUNAY")
```

Comment: Why is projection skipped? Did you tried "CONSTRAINED_DELAUNAY"? Does the standalone GP tool works?

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246735/createtin-3d-fails-with-error-000800-the-value-is-not-a-member-of-none